# rewrite url to subdomain and include full url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to prepend all of my urls from mysite.com/sub to sub.mysite.com and retain the full url using mod_rewrite ad it doesn't seem to be working.

example

if someone goes to - mysite.com/sub/1/2/3, the url in the address bar should be sub.mysite.com/1/2/3

i moved a wordpress install to my root that was previously installed to a subdirectory with a subdomain pointing to it and want to retain my url structure for posts.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks!  tried this one & it gives me a 404 when i enter a link with the subdomain (i.e. - sub.mysite.com/1/2/3)

Comment: Did you configure a virtual host for `sub.mysite.com`?

Comment: thanks.  i'm using 1and1 shared hosting - not sure i have direct access for virtual hosts.  i've setup a subdomain in the control panel that points to root.  i've added this rule & i still get 404 errors.

Comment: Can you point the sub domain to /document/root/sub?

Comment: /sub is actually a wordpress page, not a folder.  in my 1and1 hosting control panel i can only point the domain to an actual folder - right now it's set to point to the root.

i searched wordpress.org and wordpress answers here on stack exchange & couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.*)$ http://$1.mysite.com/$2 [R]
```

Comment: thanks for getting back.  tried this & it gives me error 500.

Comment: sorry try edited version

Comment: if it doesn't work, please post any relevant info from the error log and the full config (from apache2.conf, httpd.conf, virtual host conf file and/or .htaccess) that relates to the domain.

Comment: ok, i will see if i can get the log files.  thanks again!